# Создалась папка на диске C

Tags: windows

Не знаю, можно ли здесь публиковать подобного рода вопросы, но всё же рискну. 
Суть проблемы (или нет) в том, что на диске создалась скрытая папка с непонятным названием

> C:{733B5A04-6F81-4131-867F-AE1CB6674357}

Внутри находится один лишь `.dat` файл. Содержит следующее:

> (GsfkCppWokLE5L2w/NNKSAEUskblm88j8Qktn0sNSGot+heJF4HXB9BcOI5vk4wwe062QDgerApdfWVTKCKciqZzBhtoKyvTObG7qGwd9bM=)

Является ли эта папка каким-то вирусом или угрозой? Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Нет. Приведенное содержимое файла не является исполняемым.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, но всё же. Ведь чем-то оно было создано? Может ли это быть системной папкой?

Comment: В Microsoft напишите и спросите что они такое делают. Исполняемым файлов оно не является и являться не может.

Comment: Найдите этот CLSID в реестре и посмотрите, что это и зачем. Если компьютер уже перезагружался, то скорее всего эту папку можно спокойно удалить.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это temp файлы Windows Update. Появляются обычно после обновлений. Возможно обновление было некорректно установлено.